SPARQL return multiple items
Programming novice very new to SPARQL. I am trying to get the following query to get me a list of albums by Bob Dylan or Elvis Presley. The resulting table should include album name and artist:

SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P31 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q482994.
      {
        ?item p:P175 ?statement1.
        ?statement1 (ps:P175/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q392.
      }
      UNION
      {
        ?item p:P175 ?statement2.
        ?statement2 (ps:P175/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q303.
      }
    }
  }
}

I am only able to get a list of albums.

`SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?artist ?artistLabel WHERE {
VALUES ?artist {wd:Q392 wd:Q303 }
?item p:P175/ps:P175 ?artist.
?item p:P31/ps:P31/(wdt:P279*) wd:Q482994.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}`

You did it! Thank you!
